# Problem with booleans in CloudWatch Metric Filters

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

is it possible that aws CloudWatch Metric Filters do not handle boolean values?
Example JSON:

```json
    {
    "data": {
        "allMatch": true,
        "level": "INFO",
        "results": [
            {
                "expectedResult": 200,
                "matchesExpected": true,
                "result": 200,
                "type": "http-status"
            }
        ]
    },
    "stream": "stdout",
    "time": "2022-09-29T14:09:00.959390386Z"
}
```

I have tried several metric filters:
`{ $.data.allMatch = true }`, `{ $.data.allMatch = "true" }`, `{ $.data.allMatch = 1 }`, and none returns any event.

Answer (score 3):

`{ $.data.allMatch IS TRUE }` did the job...